# Does the following implication hold for $3 \times 3$ determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For real entries $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3},\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\beta_{3}$, does the following implication hold?
$\det\begin{pmatrix}   \alpha_1 &\alpha_3& \beta_2\\   \alpha_2 &\alpha_1& \beta_3\\   \alpha_3 &\alpha_2& \beta_1   \end{pmatrix}>0   \qquad\text{and}\qquad   \det\begin{pmatrix}   \alpha_1 &\beta_3& \beta_2\\   \alpha_2 &\beta_1& \beta_3\\   \alpha_3 &\beta_2& \beta_1   \end{pmatrix}>0$
implies
$\det\begin{pmatrix}   \alpha_1 &1& \beta_2\\   \alpha_2 &1& \beta_3\\   \alpha_3 &1& \beta_1   \end{pmatrix}>0   \qquad\text{OR}\qquad   \det \begin{pmatrix}   \beta_1 &1& \alpha_2\\   \beta_2 &1& \alpha_3\\   \beta_3 &1& \alpha_1   \end{pmatrix}>0
$

If it does, can it be proved?
The above problem comes from this problem [Is it impossible for determinants of these matrices to both be negative?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/426170) (on MathOverflow) - mainly equation $(9)$ of the problem linked.

With the assumption, $\det\begin{pmatrix}   \alpha_1 &\alpha_3& \beta_2\\   \alpha_2 &\alpha_1& \beta_3\\   \alpha_3 &\alpha_2& \beta_1   \end{pmatrix}\ne0   \qquad\text{and}\qquad   \det\begin{pmatrix}   \alpha_1 &\beta_3& \beta_2\\   \alpha_2 &\beta_1& \beta_3\\   \alpha_3 &\beta_2& \beta_1   \end{pmatrix}\ne0$,
we get that neither $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ nor $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ is a multiple of $(1,1,1)$.

Related things have been discussed in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140317/playing-with-3-times3-determinants)

Comment: For $\alpha_i = \beta_i=1$, we see the implication hold but does it hold in general for real entries? I have also provided context to a problem from which this arises.

Comment: Is this supported by numerical evidence? Have you tried any numerical experiment?

Comment: Apologies..I have edited the question, the second statement has an OR in it

Comment: $\alpha=[-3,0,0]\beta=[1,-2,-2]$ violate your proposition.